# How should the “bug” tag be used?

Tags: discussion, tagging, policy

Following the (brief) chat discussion starting [there](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4229525#4229525), I ask a question here a Meta about what our policy regarding the [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) should be. I thought I read somewhere in comments that [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) was to be used only for bugs confirmed by W support. On the other hand, there are good arguments for making a more liberal use of it, extending to bugs confirmed by within our own community.

So, what should be our policy regarding the [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190/how-to-report-bugs. The accepted answer there is "community consensus".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggested introducing the [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag.

Tags are useful for finding things quickly.  From MathGroup experience I know that it is useful to be aware of certain bugs, and I have spent time searching MathGroup for descriptions of old bugs that I didn't remember completely.  For example, in version 6, `Tally` is buggy when using custom comparison functions.  In version 8, `IsomorphicGraphQ` is buggy (some of the bugs have been fixed in 8.0.4).  If I use `Tally` in an older version, I need to know which version fixed the bug to make sure I won't have trouble.  For this, I'll search for it on MathGroup.  If I use `IsomorphicGraphQ`, I will want to know what triggered the bug exactly, so I can try to avoid it.  Again, I would search on MathGroup.  Unfortunately finding old MathGroup posts is usually a pain.

I think this makes it clear why I wanted to make it easy to find bugs here on Mathematica.SE.  Tagging posts which have been resolved as bugs is valuable.

The problem with a [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag is that people will add it to anything they think is a bug.  When people complain about bugs, often (I'd say, most of the time), it turns out not to be a bug (at least a bug that's useful to know about).  Often they're misunderstandings, the OP just wants something to work differently, missing features, and so on.

So I suggested that the [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag never be used on *new* questions.  We add the [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag only when it was confirmed that there is really a bug.

What does it mean that the problem "was confirmed to be a bug"?  I don't think it's necessary to have a big discussion about this.  I want to have the [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag for very practical purposes.  So let's just use common sense.  If the community seems to agree that it's a bug, tag it as a bug.  If people say they can't  reproduce it, or people explain in comments why this behaviour can be desired, or it's just a missing feature or a very very minor glitch, then don't tag it.

### Summary

- the tag's purpose is to make it easier to find bugs, so we can avoid them or work around them more easily (I have searched for information about bugs I vaguely remembered many times)
- tag it if the community agrees that it's indeed a bug and it might be useful to know about it